# .First does not throw exception on empty collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am running a linq query that should throw an exception (based on my understanding), but it does not.  There is no item in the database that fits the parameters of the query.

The following does not throw an exception, but simply returns null:

```
from i in Items
where i.ItemID == 25
select i.Values.First(v => v.AttribID == 69)
```

The following does throw an exception as expected:

```
(from i in Values
where i.ItemID == 25
where i.AttribID == 69
select i).First()
```

Through testing several different forms of the query, the only difference I can find is that .First doesn't seem to throw the exception when the lambda expression inside of returns nothing, but when .First is invoked with no parameters, it does.  Please help me understand why.

To clarify...

```
from i in Items
where i.ItemID == 25
select i
```

...returns 1 item.

See linqPad results below when testing these queries:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your first query definitely won't return null. It may return an empty collection, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: It returns 1 item equal to null.

Comment: Okay. You need to be very clear about this sort of thing. Next, is this LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL, EF, something else? A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would be really useful.

Comment: It is using Linq to SQL.

Comment: @MatthewHagemann: You do need to be very precise here. It's impossible for the first query to return `null` (either alone or together with other values) as written because in order for *anything* to be returned it must pass the test `v.AttribId == 69`, which is obviously not going to fly if `v` is `null`.

Comment: Please see screenshots I just posted from testing these queries in LinqPad.

Comment: @MatthewHagemann: as Jon says "It works because it does nothing. LINQ uses lazy evaluation, so as long as you don't attempt to touch test no queries are evaluated. If you tried e.g. test.Count() after each attempt you 'd get the exception just fine" I tried and here you go https://dotnetfiddle.net/qZglHX

Comment: @MatthewHagemann: Hmmm, those results are produced by EF's query provider, and I 'm not sure how that one decides to go about its business. Posting the classes involved might help. I can tell you for sure that if you added an `.AsEnumerable()` at the appropriate place to get out of queryable mode you would get the expected behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first query says:

> Filter `Items` to only include those with `ItemId == 25` and from each
>   filtered result `i`, select the first item `v` inside `i.Values` such
>   that `v.AttribID == 69`.

Here `First` will not throw if e.g. `Items` is empty because "from each filtered result `i`" will process exactly zero items, so `First` will never be called.

The second query says:

> Filter `Values` to only include those with `ItemId == 25` and `AttribId == 69` and give me the first matching item.

It's obvious that in this case if no matching items exist `First` cannot give you a meaningful result and will throw.

Comment: Please see edit above.  The first where returns 1 item.

Comment: @MatthewHagemann it returns one item, whose `AttribID` is not 69. Hence the result of you second query is an empty sequence, from which you try to get the first element and you get as it is expected an error. If you debug your code, you will see that the `AttribID` is not 69 for this single item. However, in you second query you are looking for that already Jon pointed out, `ItemId == 25` **and**  `AttribId == 69`, which defintely doesn't exist.

Comment: @Jon it's realy strange but not. I was ready to answer like you, but created a szample and omg, it works. Look here https://dotnetfiddle.net/qZglHX

Comment: @Baximilian: It works because it does nothing. LINQ uses lazy evaluation, so as long as you don't attempt to touch `test` no queries are evaluated. If you tried e.g. `test.Count()` after each attempt you 'd get the exception just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are using the results as parameters in our code, which come back null.  So this is not the case for us.